# Merge os valores de um Array estando dentro de outro Array

Tags: javascript, array, arraylist, merge, objetos

Tenho vários Arrays ao longo do programa para verificar identificadores
Logo em uma função eu verifico um `include` para saber se determinado identificador se encontra dentro de um objeto

o objeto tem o seguinte formato

```
  {
    suport: [ id[0], id[1], id[2], 'informations' ],
    alt: 'Whatsapp',
    description: 'Troque mensagens com os seus amigos.',
    icon: require('@/assets/images/icons/icon-whatsapp.svg')
  }
```

logo na chave `suport` eu verifico se onde chamei o `include`, me retornará um dos valores deste Array, funciona perfeitamente neste formato, visto que coloquei os IDs de forma separada, então funciona, o problema é, tenho apenas 3 identificadores neste exemplo, que no caso são todos os IDs que o programa possui, sendo só 3 ids, fica simples, o problema é, quando eu chegar a um número grande de IDs, isso se tornará muito grande,
se eu colocar `suport: [ id, 'informations' ]` ele cria um sub array dentro deste array, logo meu include não retorna pois só busca no array principal

como eu faria para juntar o array `id` dentro do array `support`?

```
id = [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ]
suport: [ id, 'informations' ]

console.log(suport) // [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'informations' ]
```

exsite como fazer isso sem uma função? visto que não posso criar uma nova função para este caso, precisaria executar ali dentro do array como por exemplo o toString que funciona porém só cria 1 index no array com os 3 ids separados por virgula, o que não serve no caso, a não ser que de para fazer o toString criar 3 index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o concat (uma função nativa assim como `.toString()`) para a junção de arrays.

`suport: [].concat(id, ['informations'])`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat

Comment: nossa, muito bom, realmente simples, não passou o concat na minha cabeça, muito obrigado